# Abstract/super/sub class-like structure for database design

Tags: mysql, database, structure

I've run my head against the wall a couple of times on this one. So I'm hoping for a little help in the right direction.

I have a table with ORDERS, one with TRAINS, one with FLIGHTS and one with BUSES. Each order should have a single way of transportation. My design has up until now consisted of a field in the ORDERS table stating the type of transport (train, flight, bus) and a field containing the forreign key to the stated type of transport.

Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: related/possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/749891/subtyping-database-tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best description I've seen of this topic is in Craig Larman's book "Applying UML and patterns" - though he writes from an object oriented, rather than database point of view.

There are 3 alternatives in the relational world (this is based on the Larman book):

- subtype per variant. So, you create a "order_flight" table with
  airline, seat choice etc, and a "order_train" with from_station,
  to_station etc. This keeps the tables nice and self-describing, but
  makes your SQL into a huge mess - it has to change for every subtype.
- single table with all possible columns: in this case, you have a    single table with all the possible fields for all subtypes. This way,
  your SQL stays far simpler - but the table becomes a huge mess, and
  you depend on your client application to "know" that flights have
  airlines, but trains don't.
- table for common attributes with subtypes storing their unique values in their own tables. This is basically what you have chosen to
  date; the relationship can be set either at the "order" table, or in 
  the subclass table.

Each option has benefits and drawbacks - especially in a situation       where you don't know in advance which subtypes you're going to need,     the first option is the simplest on the database end, but creates a      bit of a mess for the client code.

Comment: A great answer. Gives a lot of insight. I'll most certainly check the book out too. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same parent object Id for all items if they have object structure and subtype-supertype relation. do not treat them like different objects like the tree model.
[This thread shows an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/749891/subtyping-database-tables)

if you are using object oriented modeling, you would use the object oriented structure in the database, too. so if you are extending a class, you are also extending a data row, joining them on the same id numbers. that's why I say "use same id's for supertype and subtype, because you would want to join the supertype and subtype to create a subtype object.

Comment: Thanks for the answer... I'm not sure about what you mean by "object structure"?

Comment: if you are using object oriented modeling, you would use the object oriented structure in the database, too. so if you are extending a class, you are also extending a data row, joining them on the same id numbers. that's why I say "use same id's for supertype and subtype, because you would want to join the supertype and subtype to create a subtype object.

Comment: Ahh... Got it. Haven't though of it like that. Thanks.